# Mobile device 2.6V power source required

Tags: voltage, batteries, mobile

The title says it all. I need a 2.6V voltage source for a selfmade mobile device. I would appreciate any help on wich batteries (rechargable or not) to use for that. Thanks!

Further information, as requested:
The current the device needs is max 40mAmps, I have no enviromental constraints, but I would prefer to use non-rechargeable batteries you can easily buy in the EU.
The power supply system should be resistant to temperature effects.
That's honestley all information I have.
Does a pair of AA batteries connected in series and a DC DC step down component make sense? I already bought the box and the component as described in one of the comments, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Why not a lithium ion battery (~3.6V) and a voltage regulator?

Comment: This is not a shopping site, if you should need help in designing/implementing the 2.6V regulation circuit from something like a single cell lithium ion battery then we can help. provide any schematics or part numbers you are thinking of using. You should tell us what kind of current draw is expected or at least what it is powering so we can estimate it for you.

Comment: Buck converter and standard 3.7V lipo battery?

Comment: The title does NOT say it all. How accurate must the voltage be? How much current does it need to supply? How long do you expect it to last between recharges or battery replacements? Are there size, cost or any other environmental constraints?

Comment: The question can be reopened if you provide enough information IN THE question (not in comments). | What current drain? What operating life in hours of operatiom. Constantish drain or high occasionally but often low (eg like a radio RX/TX). Why 2.6V? What range of voltages is OK? (2.4 - 2.8 / 2.6 - 2.8, 2.6 - 3, ? etc - YOU say). Any size of weight constraints? ANYTHING ELSE of relevance or possible relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a simple, cheap, and rechargeable battery. Depending on what you size you need/want you could go with a phone battery (I recommend one for a Samsung phone (price to reliability) I have one from a old s1 still going strong) or just two simple nickel-cadmium batteries taped together.

Cheers!

Comment: NiCd single cells will need 3 cells. - Vend-point ~= 1V  so 3 = 3V  + LDO regulator.